# problems plotting a line with 3 colors

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am having trouble with the logic of forming an ema line for RSI with at least 3 different colors to filter signals.

This is my latest attempt.  So far the if statements I have written are not  working. I looked at another script and hypothesized that I might need to repaint in a loop to make it work. I am new to this, any input helps.

```
switchcolor = color.yellow
//red
if (rsiema <= lenema[1]) and (mtmma <= mtmma[1])
    switchcolor := color.new(color.red, 100)
//green
if (rsiema >= lenema[1]) and (mtmma >= mtmma[1])
    switchcolor := color.new(color.green, 100)
//yellow
if  (rsiema <= lenema[1]) and (mtmma >= mtmma[1])
    switchcolor := color.new(color.yellow, 100)
if (rsiema > lenema[1]) and (mtmma < mtmma[1])
    switchcolor := color.new(color.yellow, 100)

plot(lenema, "RSI EMA", color = switchcolor, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lenema = input.int(200, minval=1, title='RSI EMA Length')
```

`lenema` is an input which is an `int`. Its value will be constant.

Therefore, comparing it with its previous value does not make any sense. Its value will always be the same. And this is the reason why you are not seeing any plots when you change `lenema <= lenema[1]` to `lenema < lenema[1]`. Because `200 <= 200` is `true` but `200 < 200` is **not**.

Also, it still plots your `out`. Since your `if` checks fail, it just doesn't have any visible color that's why you odn't see it.

[image]

Comment: I changed the previous code I wrote from the way it was written in the previous post now.  Lenema is designated as the ema not out. Thanks for noticing the typo at the bottom.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry for the edits, the lenema is now rsiema